# Android Studio, Device File Explorer, не получается скачать файл

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь скачать файл с реального Android устройства, получаю вечную загрузку.

**Проблема именно с моим пакетом.** Файлы из других пакетов скачиваются без проблем.

В момент инициализации загрузки приложение не активно, в памяти устройства его нет. Устройство определяется корректно. Ошибок никаких нет, просто вечная загрузка без логов даже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил(не знаю временно или нет) удалением содержимого папки:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

и заменой их отсюда:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools